# Refreshing ListView in a fragment from ViewPager activity crashes

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an Activity with a ViewPager with **2** fragments inside it. One fragment is for adding items to ListView and the other fragment contains the ListView. Right now I have to restart the app to refresh the ListView once the items are added but I am trying to fix that. Here's how:

I'm trying to call the method to refresh ListView from ViewPager like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    library.populateListView(getApplicationContext(), library.lView); //this is line 47
    aBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}
```

This is the **populateListView** method inside **library** fragment:

```
public void populateListView(Context context, ListView listView){   
    CustomListViewAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getDatabaseArrayList(context), getActivity());  
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter); //this is line 122
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And the **getDatabaseArrayList** method code:

```
private ArrayList<RecordDetails> getDatabaseArrayList(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    Cursor c = dbHandler.getAllRecordedFiles();
    ArrayList<RecordDetails> components = new ArrayList<RecordDetails>();
    RecordDetails element;
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        element = new RecordDetails();
        element.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_NAME)));
        element.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DATE)));
        element.setDuration(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DURATION)));
        components.add(element);

        while (c.moveToNext())
        {
            element = new RecordDetails();
            element.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_NAME)));
            element.setDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DATE)));
            element.setDuration(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.MUSIC_DURATION)));
            components.add(element);
        }
    }
    return components;
}
```

My guess is that the application is crashing because I'm calling ListView from ViewPager activity like **library.lView** which probably returns **null**. But how do I fix that? I tried to declare a new ListView variable inside the ViewPager activity but it crashed probably because the activity doesn't include the ListView itself.

Here's the logcat output if it helps:

```
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at com.matejhacin.beautifulvoicerecorder.LibraryFragment.populateListView(LibraryFragment.java:124)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at com.matejhacin.beautifulvoicerecorder.MainActivity$1.onPageSelected(MainActivity.java:46)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.scrollToItem(ViewPager.java:567)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:551)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2015)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7384)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2205)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1940)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2211)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1954)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1966)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1418)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2424)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1914)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7564)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3883)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5419)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5493)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-04 08:43:44.092: E/AndroidRuntime(1779):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Let me know if I need to post the full logcat because I only posted the part I find the most important.

**UPDATE------------------------------**

Full onCreateView code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);

    // ListView
    lView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    registerForContextMenu(lView);

    //Other variables
    components = new ArrayList<RecordDetails>();
    components = getDatabaseArrayList(getActivity());
    db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    playPause = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.playPause);
    playPause.setOnClickListener(this);
    sBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    sBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekHandler = new Handler();

    populateListView(getActivity());
    seekHandler.post(run);

    return v;
}
```

**UPDATE 2---------------**

Library Fragment XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
tools:context=".LibraryFragment" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

</ListView>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_shadow_transparent" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/playPause"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Play" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/current"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="0:03"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="0:17"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

Comment: Please post your `logcat` till the line `Caused by`

Comment: `library.lView` is null;

Comment: @AbdEl-RahmanEl-Tamawy I updated my answer with full logcat but I am afraid there's no "caused by" line at all.

Comment: @GauravGupta yes, but how do I solve it?

Comment: Is `(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);` also returning `null`? Also, post the xml `fragment_library`

Comment: Are you using `customAdapter` ?

Comment: @GauravGupta Yes I just checked if it's returning null and it is. I'll post XML in a minute.

Comment: I am thinking if `(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);` returns `null`, then why `lView.setOnItemClickListener(this);` is not throwing `NPE`.

Comment: @GauravGupta Because ListView only returns null when I cann the method from another activity. If I remove the code for calling the method from another activity the app works fine. So I am thinking that onCreateView doesn't execute at all because the app crashes before it even gets to that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code is in fragment then you need to change from

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
 library.populateListView(getApplicationContext(), library.lView); //this is line 47
 aBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
 library.populateListView(getActivity(), library.lView); //this is line 47
 aBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}
```

you have to also change here because in your **populateListView** there is two parameters and while you are executing only with Context. So change it.

```
  populateListView(getActivity());
```

to

```
  populateListView(getActivity() , lv);
```

I think problem might be here

```
   components = getDatabaseArrayList(getActivity());
   db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
```

getDatabaseArrayList is your function which is executing and after that you have initialize your Database class. So it will be crashed here. So change

```
   db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
   components = getDatabaseArrayList(getActivity());
```

Have you tried with this??

```
  public void populateListView(Context context){   
   CustomListViewAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(components, getActivity());  
   lView.setAdapter(customAdapter); //this is line 122
   customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Comment: No, this code is inside Activity that hold fragment.

Comment: Is this **populateListView** function in ur Fragment class??

Comment: Yes, populateListView is in Fragment.

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: I know, I accidently posted the code without the parameter but I am actually adding the ListView with it but it still crashes.

Comment: App still crashes sadly :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to send the listview from ViewPagerActivity. Keep instance of listview in your library fragment itself, store it in onCreateView.

Change your populateListView to

```
public void populateListView(Context context){   
    CustomListViewAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getDatabaseArrayList(context), getActivity());  
    lView.setAdapter(customAdapter); //this is line 122
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but it crashed saying that lView is null.

Comment: can you post the onCreateView for library fragment? Are you assigning the listview to lView inside this method?

Comment: Yes, I am assigning the listView to lView inside the onCreateView method. I'll update my question with the code in a second.

Comment: Just check in your fragment if you are resetting the lView variable anywhere

Comment: I checked, I am not resetting it anywhere. I instantiate it in the onCreateView and then never change it or reset it again.

Comment: I think there is a race condition, as mentioned by you above. Make a check in your populateListView to not to execute any code if listview is null

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I am not at home anymore sadly but I will let you know if it works as soon as I can try it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your code is that you are trying to refresh the `listView` with the new data and this leads your app to be crashed.

To refresh your `listview` safely you need to create a method in your `customAdapter` called `setNewData(ArrayList<object> newData)`. Replace the `object` with the data type you are using and in this method do the following:

```
public void setNewDAta(ArrayList<object> newData){
    this.data = newData;
}
```

And from you main activity make the `customAdapter` a global vairable by declaring it in the start of your activity to ensure that you are using only one and create a method to pass the new data to the `adapter` and refresh it as following:

```
public void setListViewData(ArrayList<object> newData){
    customAdapter.setNewDAta(newData);
    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```